# Kinetics of a Particle: Work and Energy Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I was answering a problem in a book by not following its mass, instead I changed the values of weight A to $115.945$lb and weight B to $95.945$lb respectively. Upon calculating the total energy, it resulted to a negative value and I cannot find $V_a$ because of it. Can someone explain to me why I can't get $V_a$ and what does it mean for the total energy to be negative? Attached below is the problem :

Determine the velocity of the $60$lb block A if the
two blocks are released from rest and the $40$lb block B
moves $2$ft up the incline. The coefficient of kinetic friction
between both blocks and the inclined planes is $\mu=0.10$

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you got that negative value? For typesetting use mathjax.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the problem statement is inconsistent.

With the masses specified, there is enough friction to stop the blocks from moving at all.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two slopes (here, 60 and 30 degrees), then for the blocks to move from rest, the ratio of masses must satisfy

$${m_A \over m_B} > 2 {\sin\beta+\mu\cos\beta\over\sin\alpha-\mu\cos\alpha} \approx1.44$$

Under the original problem statement with mass ratio $60/40=1.5$ the blocks would move.  But with mass ratio $116/96=1.2$, they will not.  Is it possible that you were given a different value to use for $\mu$ and you missed it?

Comment: It was only specified in our home work that the weights of the blocks are to be changed. But can you tell me what principle is this:
mA/mB>2(sinβ+μcosβ/sinα−μcosα)≈1.44